# Selenium if/else condition with Apache Ant

Tags: selenium, ant, robotframework

Selenium test case requires an if/else condition. How can I insert an if/else condition in a Selenium test case? We have a build file which has a variable CUSTOMNAME which is passed at runtime through an Ant command. If the value is passed, then execute the below line else ignore and move on with rest of the test case.

```
Run Keyword If || ${CUSTOMNAME}>0 || Select Checkbox
```

Build file:

```
<target name="Compute" depends="init">
    <echo message="${TODAY_DE}"/>
    <exec executable="cmd">
        <arg line="/k start cmd.exe"/>
        <arg line="/k pybot"/>
        <arg line="--variable BROWSER:${Internet}"/>
        <arg line="--variable REMOTE_URL:${Remote_Url}"/>
        <arg line="--variable SERVICE:${Service}"/>
        <arg line="--variable CUSTOMNAME:${CUSTOMNAME}"/>
        <arg line="--name ${Service}_${Internet}"/>
        <arg line="--doc ${Service}_${Internet}"/>
        <arg line="-o ${output.dir}\${Service}_${Internet}_output.xml"/>
        <arg line="-l ${logs.dir}\${Service}_${Internet}_logs.xml"/>
        <arg line="-r ${docs.dir}\${Service}_${Internet}.html"/>
        <arg line="${Compute_Test}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Your question and ant script - something disconnected? Would you please rephrase the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `if` attribute to run the `Compute` `<target>` only if the `CUSTOMNAME` property is set:

```
<target name="Compute" depends="init" if="CUSTOMNAME">
```

Notice the added `if="CUSTOMNAME"`.